# How to use Magento Test Automation Framework(MTAF) test case with Jenkins?

Tags: magento, jenkins

Is there any way to use **Magento Test Automation Framework(MTAF)** with **Jenkins**? for jenkins automated testing.

Answer (score 1):

I recently done the  MTAF configuration with jenkins it works fine. simply copy and past MTAF into Jenkins workspace directory and modify the browsers.yaml file under MDAF>config>borwsers.yaml and also modify the phpunit.xml and build.xml file

This links may helps to configure:

1. http://jenkins-php.org/
2. http://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/jenkins-continuous-integration-zend-framework-and-netbeans/

Note: In the second link leave the Zend Framework Configuration things rest are same for configure MTAF with Jenkins .

Comment: I have setup Magento TAf in my system.But I do not have knowledge of phpunit testing.Could you please share some information how to run the automated test cases with MTAF?